# How can I fund my US college education?

Tags: united-states, student-loan, education, college

How can I fund my college education if I'm not given scholarship and family wouldn't be able to take loan? How did you do it in your time? 
I'd appreciate any suggestions !

Comment: Clean up your question and remove your rant. The rant doesn't help to clarify the question in anyway and it seems isn't related to your problem.

Comment: @DumbCoder I removed it all, people interested can click on edited to see it. But the term 'rant' was quite rude.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are from India from the tags in your question?

If you are non-US citizen and want to study in the US, the best option is a scholarship.
But make sure you start with you local scholarships, many people make the mistake to look for scholarships in the U.S or International Scholarships.

The competition is hard and they are hard to secure.

But, one thing that many people miss are the "niche" scholarships.
There are scholarships if you live in India and are a religious minority but there are also scholarships that are limited to non-US citizens at a particular school or study.
There are plenty of less known schools in the U.S

You could also get a student loan if you are lucky enough to know someone in US with a good credit record and they agree to be co-signer but I would also urge you to look into other countries and not only US.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the family taking a loan, *YOU* may be able to take out a loan either through the college or independently, and pay it off over the next decade or so... presuming that your wages after graduation will be high enough to cover that cost. I have no idea whether that option is available for students from other countries.

You can also find a job and work to cover some of the costs of education. That may require reducing your course load to have enough hours to be worthwhile. Jobs may exist on campus (typically more interesting and more related to what you're trying to learn, and more flexible in schedule, but perhaps less well paid) or off-campus.

I did some of both, to cover the gap between what I could come up with in other ways and what the school was charging. But my school was better than many about actively helping students find ways to fund their studies. (They took the attitude that if you could qualify for admission, they'd find a way to make it work. That is *not* typical.)

Note that studying in your own country is likely to be MUCH more affordable than studying in another country... and that going to a less-well-known (and less expensive) school for a few years, getting top grades, and then trying to transfer to a better school is a valid option, as is going to a less-well-known school for your undergrad degree, making top grades, and then trying to get admitted to a masters program at a better school.